# Track succesful steps for solve_ivp function in scipy.integrate

Tags: scipy, ode

I have a problem that requires solving a system of ODEs and I am using scipy.integrate.solve_ivp for it. When calling the integrator, I am specifying the interval of integration as well as the time points where solution is to be evaluated. The call looks something like this:

```py
Z_solution  = solve_ivp( fun= lambda t, y:  rhs_of_differential_equation( t, y, args_tuple  ),
                         t_span= time_interval, y0 = initial_array, 
                         method='RK45',
                         t_eval = np.array( [ 0.0 ] ),                                               
                         max_step   = parameters.max_step, 
                         first_step = parameters.initial_step,                                                                  
                         rtol = parameters.adaptive_step_relative_tolerance, 
                         atol = parameters.adaptive_step_absolute_tolerance,
                         )
```

This implies that I am only interested in the solution at t=0, and anything else in between is not relevant for my case. However, when calling solve_ivp, I am tracking which values of t the integrator is using, therefore, I am tracking all the "intermediate" steps in the algorithm. But I would like to know if there is a way to actually see which steps have been succesful, and not the intermediate ones. It seems to me that the call above would integrate everything down to t=0.0 but does not tell you whether an integration step was succesful or not... I would appreciate some help in here, thanks!

ADDITIONAL INFO: My solutions vector y is in fact dependent on a grid that also scales with t. That is, if y is my solution of the ODE, it will consist of N points, where N is the size of the grid ( for a fixed value of t ). This means, for the end-point of integration t=0.0, my solution y is an array with N elements. But, the grid where values are calculated is also dependent on the value of t. Is there a way to consistently change the grid throughout the integration algorithm? I have tried passing the grid in the initial conditions array, but does not seem to work proper..

**EDIT-2:** Here I have written a little code to understand this. My problem has very big varying scales and therefore, I want to let the integrator to choose the necessary time steps for me, therefore I DO NOT want to select beforehand the t_evals to a fixed number of points; I only need the initial and final times of the interval. For times in between, the integrator will make the necessary step adjustment in order to not exceed the tolerances. Then, my problem wants to identify these internal points ( the points between [0,10] that the integrator was able to calculate ). The object SolveODE inside the bunch object returned by the solve_ivp function seems to have "ts" values, along with a **call** method that in principle retrieves the generated solution at those time steps. Here is the code for a simple exponential decay function:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyt


def my_fun2( t, y, *args ):    
    return -0.5*y    

vals = np.array( [ 100 ] )    
args_tuple = ( 0.01, 0.5 )

Z_solution  = solve_ivp( fun= lambda t, y: my_fun2( t, y, args_tuple  ),
                                         t_span= [0.0, 10], y0 = vals, 
                                         method='RK45',
                                         t_eval =   [0.0, 10],
                                         dense_output  = True,                                                                  
                                         rtol=1e-7, atol = 1e-7,                                           
                   )  

OdeSol  = Z_solution.sol
y_sol = OdeSol.__call__( OdeSol.ts  )[0] 
ts    = OdeSol.ts 

x = np.linspace( 0, 10, 1000 )
analytic = 100*np.exp( -0.5*x )

for s in range( 0, len(vals) ):    
    pyt.plot( ts, y_sol, 'ob', x, analytic, '-r' )
    pyt.show()
```

and the analytic solution and the points by ( ts, y_sol ) gives:

[code plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUGjQ.png)

Then, if I understand correctly, the blue dots are the points where the integrator found solutions in the interval [0,10] WITHOUT exceeding the tolerances. If you make the tolerances smaller, then of course the number of blue points gets reduced, can anyone confirm this?

On top of that, what I need for my system is to somehow tell the function at each ts point to stop, perform some grid adjustment of the y_sol found at that point, and continue the integration. Is there a way to do this by using solve_ivp? I can only think on including this functionality myself in the solve_ivp , but I really do not want this as this would imply modifiying the solve_ivp code to allow for such functionality, many thanks!

Comment: You mean to say that `y` itself is a function of some space variable `x` represented by its values over an adaptive grid or similar? How would you compute the representation of the sum of two such functions? While it is then possible to implement Runge-Kutta methods for such objects, this is not possible within the frame of `solve_ivp` because that depends on the state vectors being arrays of fixed dimension.

Comment: Yes y(x) is to be evaluated over the x grid at every t step. However, decreasing t corresponds to a decrease in the bounds of the x grid. For example, if I start my initial conditions at T=10. then I have a grid of say, 100 points in the interval [ -10, 10 ] , and y(x,t) needs to be evaluated in that precise grid. As t  goes to the end of the flow ( t=0.0), the grid is changin its boundary values, so in the end the final grid x has bounds [ - eps, eps ] but with the same number of points all the way down. Isn't there a way to make this work in solve_ivp? What is suggested instead then? Thanks

Comment: To clarify further, the dimension of the arrays always stays the same regardless of the value of t, as the grid x where I have to evaluate y has always the same number of points.

Comment: You could map everything to the constant interval [-1,1], the t-dependent grid spacing then enters into the coefficients.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you propose; the grid is needed along with all intermediate steps of the integrator, not only the "succesfully" completed steps I believe

Comment: There might be some communication problem: What are "successfully completed steps", are you talking about the interna of the step size controller in the solver? // If you have a function u(x,t) for the domain |x|<=X(t) then you can parametrize this on a more common rectangular region as `v(xi,t)=u(xi*X(t),t)`, the proposal was to re-formulate the equations for `v`.

Comment: No, solout is strictly a reporting function or observer hook. There is no provision to manipulate the internal state of the solver. You would have to restart the integration for the new situation. Also, in the way that you describe your idea, you would seriously worsen the accuracy of the solution, this piecewise constant approximation of the boundary makes the input to the solver an order 1 approximation which in turn makes the full method order 1 independent of the integration method used.

Comment: Thanks for the continuous replies;  I am seriosly struggling to come up with a solution on this. I have read that adaptive grid methods are commonly used in the numerical solution of PDEs. Here, the problem at hand can be considered 2D (as you mentioned), where I know the initial grid X(t) = [ x_1, ..., x_N ] and the points of y(t) = [  y(x_1), ..., y(x_N) ] at fixed time. As the time step is decreased, the solution in the x grid needs to be adjusted because the initial X(t) changes to X(t+dt); in other words, solving for y(t +dt) yields y(t + dt , X(t) ) and we would need y( t+dt, X(t+dt))

Comment: I would say that the method design problem should be discussed in scicomp.SE along with more of its mathematical background (using mathjax there). The implemented solvers only apply to problems `y'=f(t,y,p)` where `y` is a flat vector/array of fixed dimension. All translation to variable grid geometry etc. has to be done inside the ODE function `f`. To the outside, it has to be a black box.

Comment: Or you could implement your own solver routine, for RK45 it is not that complicated (apart from selecting the variant of DOPRI5), where `y` is a vector object from some fixed vector space where all interna are handled by the vector (space) class.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply; yes after doing some research this seems to be the case as you mentioned (the kind of black-box functionality of solve_ivp). I came out with some solution by creating and additional module of the scipy.integrate._ivp which is an exact copy of the ivp module, except that now there are additional functions in it. The internal steps of the solver can be accessed if we put t_eval=None; then if one goes to the body of solve_ivp, one sees where the (t,y) values are appended to the SolveODE object "y" attribute. Before making this,I call the additional functions to adapt y

Comment: But note again that if you do not change the grid geometry continuously, you make O(dt) errors in it which translate to O(dt^2) errors in the value updates making the whole procedure order 1, so that the actual errors you encounter can be much larger than the given error tolerances.